# Make code markup button more obvious

Tags: feature-request, markdown, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [More obvious formatting help for new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25079/more-obvious-formatting-help-for-new-users)

Almost all of my edits to questions on SO consist of selecting the code and hitting the code formatting button. It seems clear to me that new users don't notice the code button or don't realise they need to do something special for code fragments.

Could there be some hint text (limited by reputation maybe?) saying - "If you include some code in your question, please format it using this button [arrow pointing to code button]" or equivalent?