# Unable to create a question at SO: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code

Tags: support, code-formatting

What's wrong with the following question? I get this error:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

---

I'm wondering if there's a possibility to change Dependency Injection configuration file at a runtime and force DI container to re-resolve object graph created before according to this new configuration.

To clarify my idea, I'll get you a simple example:

Imagine that you've got the following project structure:

- `Common.dll` library which contains `IDoable` interface:

```
    public interface IDoable
    {
        void Do();
    }
```

- `LibraryA.dll` library which requires `Common.dll` and contains a realization of `IDoable` interface:

```
    public class A : IDoable
    {
        public void Do()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A.Do()");
        }
    }
```

- `LibraryB.dll` library which is quite similar to `LibraryA.dll`:

```
    public class B : IDoable
    {
        public void Do()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B.Do()");
        }
    }
```

- A `Test.exe` console application which references only to `Common.dll` library and uses DI container to resolve references to the `IDoable` interface:

```
    IDoable instance = _Container.Resolve<IDoable>();
    instance.Do();
```

DI configuration file contains the following section (currently I'm using [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/), but it doesn't really matter):

```
    <autofac>
        <components>
            <component
                    type="LibraryA.A, LibraryA"
                    service="Common.IDoable, Common" />
        </components>
    </autofac>
```

So, when I run my `Test.exe`, I'll see the output from `LibraryA.dll`.

Everything is going OK so far. Now imagine that you want to switch your application from `LibraryA.dll` to `LibraryB.dll` in a runtime, without restarting the application. Any ideas? OK, you can use `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor changes in DI configuration file and reinitialize DI container every time the file is changed. So, if you'll change configuration file accordingly and call again

```
    IDoable instance = _Container.Resolve<IDoable>();
    instance.Do();
```

you'll see the output from `LibraryB.dll`.

OK, finally we're facing the problem. When using DI, you don't resolve references every time before using them. Normally, you resolve object graph in some initialization code. So, even after you changed the config file and DI container is reconfigured, your previously resolved objects stay the same until you re-resolve them. And there could be a lot of such objects, so calling `Resolve<T>()` every time before using object may be very painful.

So, how would you on-the-fly update previously resolved objects after changing DI configuration? Or maybe there is some DI container already able to do that automatically?

Comment: My best guess would be that the code-finder misinterprets your `<pre><code>` as being something you should have indented. Does it work if you get rid of the manual code blocks, and indent all code underneath the list items by 8 spaces from the left?

Comment: In this post all your code blocks have 4 spaces too much of indentation and an empty first row.

Comment: [This post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/87611/simple-method-for-reliably-detecting-code-in-text) talks about some of the heuristics used to determine poorly formatted code on SO (which is, itself, linked to from [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98436/168428) by Jeff Atwood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the bulleted list, use 8 spaces to indent each line of a code block that's in a list item. Doing so rather than using `<pre>` tags also allows your code blocks to be highlighted by prettify.

---

I'm wondering if there's a possibility to change Dependency Injection configuration file at a runtime and force DI container to re-resolve object graph created before according to this new configuration.

To clarify my idea, I'll get you a simple example:

Imagine that you've got the following project structure:

- `Common.dll` library which contains `IDoable` interface:

  ```
  public interface IDoable
  {
      void Do();
  }
  ```
- `LibraryA.dll` library which requires `Common.dll` and contains a realization of `IDoable` interface:

  ```
  public class A : IDoable
  {
      public void Do()
      {
          Console.WriteLine("A.Do()");
      }
  }
  ```
- `LibraryB.dll` library which is quite similar to `LibraryA.dll`:

  ```
  public class B : IDoable
  {
      public void Do()
      {
          Console.WriteLine("B.Do()");
      }
  }
  ```
- A `Test.exe` console application which references only to `Common.dll` library and uses DI container to resolve references to the `IDoable` interface:

  ```
  IDoable instance = _Container.Resolve<IDoable>();
  instance.Do();
  ```

DI configuration file contains the following section (currently I'm using [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/), but it doesn't really matter):

```
<autofac>
    <components>
        <component
                type="LibraryA.A, LibraryA"
                service="Common.IDoable, Common" />
    </components>
</autofac>
```

So, when I run my `Test.exe`, I'll see the output from `LibraryA.dll`.

Everything is going OK so far. Now imagine that you want to switch your application from `LibraryA.dll` to `LibraryB.dll` in a runtime, without restarting the application. Any ideas? OK, you can use `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor changes in DI configuration file and reinitialize DI container every time the file is changed. So, if you'll change configuration file accordingly and call again

```
IDoable instance = _Container.Resolve<IDoable>();
instance.Do();
```

you'll see the output from `LibraryB.dll`.

OK, finally we're facing the problem. When using DI, you don't resolve references every time before using them. Normally, you resolve object graph in some initialization code. So, even after you changed the config file and DI container is reconfigured, your previously resolved objects stay the same until you re-resolve them. And there could be a lot of such objects, so calling `Resolve<T>()` every time before using object may be very painful.

So, how would you on-the-fly update previously resolved objects after changing DI configuration? Or maybe there is some DI container already able to do that automatically?