# Don't consider inline code spans as code for the purposes of the quality filter

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, link-only-answers, quality-filter, jsfiddle

From my `earlier question`, [Detect attempts at disguising meaningless text as code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169694/detect-attempts-at-disguising-meaningless-text-as-code-blocks):

> Currently, the quality filter only asks that you have a code block before it will accept your submission of a post containing a jsFiddle link. Without a block of code, [the submission is rejected with an instruction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code).
>
> Unfortunately, it doesn't matter what you put in that code block, as long as at least one line of text begins with four spaces to make an indented block of code in Markdown and isn't entirely whitespace. This means as long as you have a non-whitespace code block *somewhere* in your post, you can submit it with a fiddle link. It doesn't have to be actual code.

The `quality filter` also considers just having `any` text surrounded by a `pair of backticks` to `form` an `inline code span`, as `sufficient code` for a post to be let through.

Given that `jsFiddle links` typically consist of `complete code snippets` that `span` one or more `lines of code` and would `almost invariably benefit` from `syntax highlighting`, it seems in poor form to consider `inline code spans` as `code` for this `purpose`, because `inline code spans` are typically used to refer to `things from code` within `written prose`, as opposed to `complete snippets`.

`Plus`, it's an even `cheaper workaround`: just add one or more `pairs of backticks` to `anything`. Add the [`rampant misuse` of `backticks` for `emphasis`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right) to `that` and you get plenty of `false negatives` which `cannot` be `fixed` by `somebody else` unless they extract the `code` from the `fiddle` while also `fixing` the `misused backticks`.

`Thus`, I feel allowing this is `counter-productive`. If a `post` linking to a `fiddle` requires `code` coming `directly` from the `fiddle` in order to be allowed, and that code is usually a `complete code sample` rather than `something` that can be referred to `mid-sentence`, then there's no `good reason` to consider or allow `inline code spans` as such. These should be `excluded` from the `filter criteria`.

In other words, for something to be considered `code` for the purposes of the `quality filter`, it should be in a `code block`. Just putting `text` in an `inline code span` should not be `sufficient` to `pass`.

Comment: Ohh my precious eyes.

Comment: @hims056: Imagine normal text is lava and you have to get from top to bottom. Fun for all the family.

Comment: Related/duplicate of some of it it's difficult to read so I'm not certain exactly what you're asking :-) - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175658/do-backticks-count-as-code-for-jsfiddle-links

Comment: @ben: Your question ends with "If backticks are 'code' in this situation then this is a feature request to stop them from being considered as such." so I would consider this to be a duplicate since my question here is asking the same thing. I know how you feel though; it's probably not as easy for you to read as it is for people who use backticks to "improve readability" :)

Comment: I remember a post like this from months back... I wanted to kill that one too. =)

Comment: @J. Steen: [This one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back) by any chance?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Yes. I hate you so much. But at the same time, respect your tenacity! ^^

Comment: Why do you love backticks so much? I guess I need to raise a feature request to stop @BoltClock'saUnicorn from using backticks from here onwards.

Answer (score 1):

To be `honest`, I have had my `fair share` of `answers` that contain only `inline code spans` with links to `jsFiddle`, where the `inline code spans` actually represent `code`. [`Here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535935/why-is-there-a-space-on-top-of-unordered-list-items/14536062#14536062) is `one` of them. The `small fragments` of `code` being `represented` are context enough that including an `entire snippet` of `code` would be `unnecessary` (`albeit` probably still `beneficial`).

Given that `inline code spans` are relatively `trivial` to deal with, `especially` since there's probably going to be `only one` or `two` to remove (since that's `all` you `need` for the `quality filter` to `let your post through`), it `probably` isn't worth forcing `every` post to include a `great big code block` at the cost of legitimate uses of `inline code spans`. `Besides`, as `already pointed out` in my earlier question, it's equally `cheap` to `work around` either way.

Comment: Related: [Please ‘never’ use   or ˋbackticksˋ for emphasis.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722) That’s what *italics* are for, [amongst other things](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/364).  And do please go easy on the bold, too, while you’re at it.